# Javascript set negative margin

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to Javascript and I'm building a website from scratch for learning purposes. I stumbled upon what I think is an error. I tried to set negative margin on one of my elements and it didn't work. This is the line that doesn't work for me:

```
document.getElementById("wrapper").style.marginLeft="-250px";
```

How can I set negative margin on my element with JavaScript?
Here's my html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper_inside">
        <img src="images/profile.png">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    color: white;
    background-color: #565656;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

-----------Edit-------------
Ok so the problem in my javascript but earlier. I had toggle function and instead of `$element.style.marginLeft=='0px'` I did `$element.style.marginLeft=='0'`

Comment: Can you give the HTML?

Comment: Do you have your script just before `</body>` so when it's executed all the HTML elements have been loaded?

Comment: It might be some CSS issues with `position`. Not with JS

Comment: Yes the script is before </body>. The line that executes showing my wrapper is working only the hiding one is not. I toogle the viewing state of my elements by setting negative margin and margin 0.

Answer (score 4):

1. Set an id instead of a class in the div tag. You are using `getElementById()`. It does exactly that. So you need to provide an id that exists, not a class. If you want to select an element by class. Just use `getElementsByClass()` (will return an object containing all elements of that class.
2. You need another wrapper in order to apply the margin. Not sure if this is what you're looking for...

```js
document.getElementById("wrapper").style.marginLeft = "-250px";
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: white;
  background-color: #565656;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.big-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-wrapper">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper_inside">
      <img src="images/profile.png">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are three basic ways of selecting HTML elements with JavaScript:

```
// by id
document.getElementById('myId');

// by class considering your element is the first in DOM to use this class
document.getElementsByClassName('myClass')[0];

// by selector
document.querySelectorAll('.myClass')[0];
// or 
document.querySelector('#myId');
```